# How to use mcheck for Heap Consistency Check in GNU C?

Tags: c++, c, gdb, gnu

I am trying to understand how heap consistency checking works in GNU C Library. I Refered http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html#Heap-Consistency-Checking

Here is a sample program I have written. I expected as suggested in the manual if I run in gdb and call `mcheck(0)` my custom `abortfn` would be called. But it isn't getting called.

What am I missing here?

included necessary headers.

```
void *abortfn(enum mcheck_status status)
{
    switch(status) {
    case MCHECK_DISABLED:
            printf("MEMCHECK DISABLED\n");
            break;
    default:
            printf("MEMCHECK ENABLED\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("This is mcheck testing code\n");
    int *a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a = 10;
    printf("A: %d\n", *a);
    free(a); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Calling `mcheck(0)` sets the *default* abort function, not yours. Read the reference closer.

Comment: An additional point is that the default abort function will be called when calling mcheck(0) only if there is an inconsistency detected. I do not see any memory consistency issue with your main() code.

Answer (score 3):

Today, compiling with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is more convenient.

However, the [very](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html) documentation that you are linking to says:

> it is too late to begin allocation checking once you have allocated anything with malloc

So start your `main` as

```
 int main() {
   mcheck(abortfn);
```

However, your `abortfn` should return `void` so code it as:

```
 void abortfn(enum mcheck_status status) {                                  
   switch(status) {                                                        
    case MCHECK_DISABLED:                                           
        printf("MEMCHECK DISABLED\n");                 
        break;                               
    default:                             
        printf("MEMCHECK ENABLED\n");                    
} }
```